# Dilation of a set is a closed set?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be complete normed space. Suppose $B \subseteq X$ is a set. Define for scalar $k$

$$ kB = \{ x \in X : x = kb , \; \; \; b \in B \} $$

Is $kB$ a closed set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric and norm, $B = (0, 1)$, $k = 2$.